# Haskell memorizing type signature in detail

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-signature

Have this example:

```
type Min = Int 
data Prio = Low | Medium | High deriving Show
data Task = Task {
    taskDesc    :: String 
  , taskPrio    :: Prio
  , taskDur     :: Min
} deriving Show 
taskFromTuple :: (String, Prio, Min) -> Task 
taskFromTuple (tDesc, tPrio, tDur) = Task tDesc tPrio tDur
-- tasksFromList :: Functor f => f (String, Prio, Min) -> f Task
tasksFromList = fmap taskFromTuple
```

If I omit `tasksFromList` typesig I get an error 'Ambiguous type var...'. Now this typesig seems relatively simple, but still one of many to memorize. Do I need to learn typesigs that well, that I can come up with exactly the right one, prior to writing the function? 
I basically understand what the typesigs mean, but they can get quite complex easily.

Although related to the question on monomorphism restriction, the question is different, owing to the fact that I wanted to know if to put a lot of effort in learning to write typesigs prior to functions or to concentrate on functions and hope type inference would help me out. @Chi provided a clear answer.

Comment: In Haskell, it is strongly recommended to write a type signature before writing the actual definition for a function. This helps the compiler to spot some errors early, usually providing meaningful error messages. Without type signatures, the errors can be must less clear, or -even worse- the code might type check without errors, but with an unexpected type. The compiler will likely raise type errors much later in the code using the function, puzzling the programmer who does not understand what's wrong at that point. Indeed, there's nothing wrong there, the problem is above.

Comment: Your name implies you don't *want* to support arbitrary functors anyway, only the list functor. Use `map` instead of `fmap` to eliminate the polymorphism responsible for the monomorphism restriction rearing its ugly had.

Comment: Further, certain advanced Haskell features (rank N types, type families, GADTs, ...) can not work unless the programmer provides types explicitly. Haskell is a programming languages where types are a central notion. Programming in Haskell with certain libraries sometimes requires thinking about types more than thinking about code.

Comment: @chepner: sorry. Unlucky naming. It is a genuine question, considering the usual typesigs are relatively easy to understand, but wandering into the realm of abstracts it get a lot harder. Next to that, type inference does not save me in the example.

Comment: @chi, thanks for the second comments. I will put some more effort in understanding the typesigs and designing them prior to the code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "memorizing". You don't memorize type signatures, you just decide what arguments your function accepts and what it returns, and you write that down. It's always good to do this before you write the function, as the typesig is less complicated, so you're less likely to get bogged down in the implementation details. It seems like what you're having trouble with is possibly what specific types or typeclasses mean (like `Functor`) and when to use them in a typesig? That just comes with practice, and usually you needn't be so general unless you have a reason.

Comment: @DarthFennec, when dealing with polymorphic recursion, it's pretty common for the (mandatory) type signature to be the hardest part.

Comment: @DarthFennec, dfeuer, thanks! Helpful comments. 'Memorizing' is the wrong choice of words. However: usually `:type` helps me out (in learning) in `GHCi`, but that won't work in the  example code, since it won't compile. That led me to draw the conclusion that I first have to design the typesig, which I find very hard in some cases.